# tablesorter.js not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have an issue in table-sorter.js after ajax call.
I have created a div as below:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<input type="button" id="make-table" value="Make Table" />
```

After completion of page load when I click on button with id "make-table", an ajax call will occure and create a table in html dynamically.

Now I want to make sortable to this table using table-sortable.js.

But its not working for me.

My AJAX Call is here :

```
jQuery("#details-wrapper").on('click', 'tr.match-detail', function() {
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        var array = id.split("#");
        var round_id = array[0];
        var round_matches_id = array[1];
        var team1_id = array[2];
        var team2_id = array[3];

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',   // Adding Post method
            url: XYZ_AJAX_URL, // Including ajax file
            data: {"action": "get_matches_details", "round_id":round_id, "round_matches_id":round_matches_id, "team1_id":team1_id, "team2_id":team2_id}, // Sending data dname to post_word_count function.
            success: function(data){ // Show returned data using the function.
                data = removeZeros(data);
                jQuery("#round-matches-table").remove();
                jQuery("#details-wrapper").html(data);
                jQuery(".team2_details").hide();
                jQuery( "#details-wrapper" ).scroll();
                jQuery("#matches-details-table").tableSorter();
            }
        });
    });
```

Please guide me in this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call $("#mytable").tablesorter() again AFTER you inject the table and each time you change or delete and re-add the rows.

Answer (score 1):

1. After js error  (you can see it in console), all js stops working. Check your errors and fix them.
2. If you have binded some objects and change them, you should re-bind them after ajax updation.